# Experimental confirmation of Einstein Equation in presence of electromagnetic matter

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, spacetime

Is there any experimental confirmation of the Einstein equation $G_{\mu\nu}=-T_{\mu\nu}$ for space-time regions where $T_{\mu \nu}$ does not vanish?

Update: I'm rather interested in the scenerio where the $T_{\mu \nu}$ is the electromagnetic stress-energy tensor.

Update: This question was flagged as a duplicate, but, here the context is specifically with respect to electromagnetic matter. The premise is that since the geodetic equation of general relativity falls flat on its face while describing motion of a charged particle in presence of electromagnetism, the Einstein equation *might* follow suit. Hence the question.

Comment: The [Einstein field equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_field_equations) are usually written as $G_{\mu\nu}=\frac{8\pi G}{c^4}T_{\mu\nu}$. Where did you get that negative sign? I’ve never seen that convention.

Comment: From Einstein himself. Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_field_equations "Authors including Einstein have used a different sign in their definition for the Ricci tensor which results in the sign of the constant on the right side being negative"

Comment: Also refer to https://www.relativitycalculator.com/pdfs/einstein_1916_general_relativity_paper.pdf page 185

Comment: Thanks! I learned GR 50 years ago but you taught me something new.

Comment: $T_{\mu\nu}$ is the electromagnetic stress tensor during the [radiation-dominated era](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale_factor_(cosmology)#Radiation-dominated_era) of Big Bang cosmology, but I don’t know how well our understanding of this era has been experimentally tested. It ended before the time of the cosmic microwave background.

Comment: Thank you @Ghoster.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the entire field of cosmology is based on the FLRW metric in GR which is a non-vacuum spacetime.

What has not been tested is GR in matter with a lot of angular momentum. That would be interesting because it could distinguish between GR and Einstein-Cartan gravity.

Comment: Thank you. I should expand my question to include Electromagnetism as matter. That was my key interest in the first place.

Comment: Don’t LIGO-detected mergers of neutron stars test GR in matter with a lot of angular momentum?

Comment: Einstein-Cartan gravity matches GR in the vacuum outside of matter with a lot of angular momentum. It is only actually inside the matter, where $T_{\mu\nu}\ne 0$ that they differ